# Clase única por click javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una función que inserta una clase a los botones, esta clase cambia el color de los mismos, solo que esta función no logro ponérsela a todos para que todos a medida que se de click se agregue la clase.

solo funciona con uno, y además necesito darle click a el botón 'color' para que cambie de color y busco es agregar la clase al botón que le de click, sin necesidad de otro, todo esto con javascript

```js
function color() {
var color = document.querySelector(".buttons button");
color.classList.toggle("edit");
}
```

```css
.edit{
background-color: #ff0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="color()">color</button>
```

Comment: [querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) Devuelve el primer elemento del documento...que coincida con el grupo especificado de selectores.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A continuación el código en JS puro y su explicación:

```js
// Seleccionanos todos los botones
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons button");

// Creamos un listener para cada botón, y ordenamos que cambie la clase cuando se le da clic al botón
buttons.forEach(button =>{
  button.addEventListener("click",_ =>{
    button.classList.toggle("edit");
  })
})


//Si lo que quieres es que solo el botón presionado tenga la clase

let buttons2 = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons2 button");

buttons2.forEach(button =>{
  button.addEventListener("click",_ =>{
    buttons2.forEach(button =>{
      button.classList.remove("edit");
    })
    button.classList.toggle("edit");
  })
})
```

```css
body{
height: 100vh;
margin: 0;
}
.buttons{
height: 50%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.buttons2{
height: 50%;
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
.edit{
color: #fff;
background-color: blue !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
</div>

<div class="buttons2">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
</div>
```

**Ejecuta el snippet para que lo veas funcionando.**

También te dejo como hacerlo con JQuery:

```
$(".buttons button").click(function(){
    $(this).toggleClass("edit");
});

//Si quieres que solo quede activo al que le das clic y que los demás queden con su estilo normal prueba con el siguiente grupo de botones:

$(".buttons2 button").click(function(){
    $(".buttons2 button").removeClass("edit");
    $(this).toggleClass("edit");
});
```

Comment: Gracias, y cómo sería con el classList.toggle de javascript?

Comment: this.classList.toggle("rgba"); Dentro de la función click. Si fue útil por favor márcala como la respuesta solicitada.

Comment: @Header90, puedes usar jquery por el manejo de selectores, te ahorras mucho espacio como el ejemplo indicado, que es claro y limpio.

Comment: jQuery no ahorra apenas nada en este caso, con sólo Javascript se puede hacer lo mismo.

Comment: El OP no está preguntando sobre jQuery, sino sobre JavaScript, por favor, adapta tu respuesta a Vanilla JS

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa ya lo corregí, sino que anteriormente la pregunta era distinta, la han vuelto a formular completamente.

Answer (score 6):

[document.querySelector](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

> Devuelve el primer elemento del documento (...) que coincida con el grupo especificado de selectores.

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

> Devuelve una NodeList estática (no viva) que representa una lista de elementos del documento que coinciden con el grupo de selectores indicados.

Teniendo en cuenta esto podés asignarle el `onclick` a cada uno de los botones con un `forEach`, y de paso al `toggle` para que los cambie también con un `forEach`.

```js
var colores = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons button");

colores.forEach(function(color) {
  color.onclick = function() {
    this.classList.toggle("edit");
  }
})


function colorTodos() {
  colores.forEach(function(color) {
    color.classList.toggle("edit");
  })
}
```

```css
.edit {
  background-color: #ff0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
</div>

<br>
<button onclick="colorTodos()">color</button>
```

Comment: ¿No crees que es mejor utilizar addEventListener('click', colorTodos()) en lugar de añadirlo a la propiedad onclick()?

Comment: @FernandoCarrascosa hay varias cosas para mejorar pero no quería alejarme mucho del original y mostrar el foreach en acción

Answer (score 3):

Una posible solución a través del uso de solamente **CSS** y de sus útiles pseudo-clases:

```css
.buttons button:focus {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.buttons2 button:focus:nth-child(1) {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}

.buttons2 button:focus:nth-child(2) {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
}

.buttons2 button:focus:nth-child(3) {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.buttons2 button:focus:nth-child(4) {
  background-color: orange;
  color: white;
}

.buttons2 button:focus:nth-child(5) {
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
</div>

<br>

<div class="buttons2">
  <button>1</button>
  <button>2</button>
  <button>3</button>
  <button>4</button>
  <button>5</button>
</div>
```

> La pseudo-clase `:focus` **CSS** representa un elemento (como una entrada de
>   formulario) que ha recibido el foco. Generalmente se activa cuando el
>   usuario hace clic, toca un elemento o lo selecciona con la tecla "Tab"
>   del teclado.
>
> La pseudo-clase `:nth-child()` de **CSS** coincide con uno o más elementos
>   en función de su posición entre un grupo de hermanos.

Answer (score 1):

Esta es mi respuesta: Primero selecciono todos los botones situados dentro de un elemento que tiene la clase `.buttons`.

```
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons button");
```

Después para cada botón (color) `buttons.forEach`

al hacer click en el botón `button.addEventListener("click",...`

le agrega o le quita la clase `.edit`: `button.classList.toggle("edit");`

Espero que esto es lo que preguntabas.

```js
// selecciona todos los botones cuyo padre es .buttons
let buttons = document.querySelectorAll(".buttons button");

// para cada boton al hacer click le agrega o le quita la clase edit
buttons.forEach(button =>{
  button.addEventListener("click",()=>{button.classList.toggle("edit");})
})
```

```css
.edit{
background-color: #ff0 !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
<button>1</button>
<button>2</button>
<button>3</button>
<button>4</button>
<button>5</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Esta es una forma de realizarlo asignado un id a los botones, al dar clic cambias el color de la celda usando la clase rgba:

```js
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(e){
        var idClicked = e.target.id;         
      document.getElementById(idClicked).className = 'rgba';
         
      });
    });
```

```css
        body{
        height: 100vh;
        margin: 0;
        }
        .button-color{
        height: 100%;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
        justify-content: center;
        }
        .rgba{
        color: #fff;
        background-color: blue !important;
        }
```

```html
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

        <div class="button-color">
        <button id="btn1">1</button>
        <button id="btn2">2</button>
        <button id="btn3">3</button>
        <button id="btn4">4</button>
        <button id="btn5">5</button>
        </div>
```